# Angular -- getting to item page (dynamic url)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I am working on a basic navigation structure -- Login, a list of items, and clicking on any one of them should take me to a page about the item I just clicked on. The navigation between pages works, except for that I cannot get into the item page itself. The url changes when I click on an item, but the page doesn't change and the item page's controller never gets called.

Here's the routing in the app.config:

```
$stateProvider

.state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
  controller: 'LoginCtrl'
})

.state('content', {
  url: '/content',
  templateUrl: 'templates/content.html',
  controller: 'LandingCtrl'
})

.state('content.item', {
  url: '/:itemId',
  templateUrl: 'templates/item.html',
  controller: 'ItemCtrl'
});
```

The code from the list of items (from which we should be able to click on one and go to its own page):

```
  <a ng-repeat="item in items" href="#/content/{{item.id}}">
  </a>
```

The code for the item controller (to be called when routed to the item page):

```
.controller('ItemCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, ItemFactory) {
    $scope.itemInfo = ItemFactory.getItemById($stateParams.itemId);
});
```

Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong? I've read the docs and it seems to be correct.

Comment: Do you really have an `href` on a `<div>` or is that a typo?

Comment: I'm using Ionic framework, so it's actually on an <ion-item> tag, but I didn't want to get into specifics. Under the hood it makes an <a> with an href. Sorry for the confusion.